# Use preact with babel-standalone

Tags: javascript, babeljs, preact

I try to get preact working with babel-standalone.
This means I have to load a new [preset](https://github.com/developit/babel-preset-preact) for preact.

I cannot figure out how to load this preset with `Babel.registerPreset`.

A temporary workaround is to rename "React.createElement" with "h" (preact equivalent for React.createElement) in the babel-standalone sources.

Any idea how to load presets with `Babel.registerPreset` or create a own one?

Comment: Why are you not using a `.babelrc` for this?

Comment: "Note that .babelrc doesn't work in @babel/standalone..."(https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is working with Preact and Babel from a cdn, directly in the browser with no build. You can even import a component from a file (drawing.js).

Couldn't get it to run in the snippets, but just make three files: index.html, index.js, and drawing.js

index.js

```js
window.React = { createElement: preact.h }
const { Drawing } = await imp("./drawing.js");

const App = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Just a test</h1>  
        <Drawing/>      
      </div>
    );
  };

  
  preact.render(<App/>, document.body);

  async function imp(path, requestOrigin) {
    const { href } = new URL(
      path,
      requestOrigin
        ? requestOrigin.slice(0, requestOrigin.lastIndexOf("/"))
        : location.href
    ); // so the paths won't be messed up
    const res = await fetch(href);
    const text = await res.text();
    const { code } = Babel.transform(text, { presets: ["react"] });
    return await import(
      `data:application/javascript,${encodeURIComponent(code)}`
    );
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/preact/7.2.0/preact.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    async function imp(path, requestOrigin) {
      const { href } = new URL(
        path,
        requestOrigin
          ? requestOrigin.slice(0, requestOrigin.lastIndexOf("/"))
          : location.href
      ); // so the paths won't be messed up
      const res = await fetch(href);
      const text = await res.text();
      const { code } = Babel.transform(text, { presets: ["react"] });
      return await import(
        `data:application/javascript,${encodeURIComponent(code)}`
      );
    }
  </script>
  <script defer type="text/babel" data-type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='root'></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

```js
export function Drawing() {
    return <p>Random drawing</p>;
  }
```